# Windows Form is not staying on screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Visual Studio 2022. VB.NET. Windows Form. Two forms. Splash & Disclaimer. Splash form should stay on screen for 3 seconds, unload and load Disclaimer from. Splash form is working great, but Disclaimer for does not stay on screen for next action. For now the disclaimer form is empty. I have added a timer control in the splash form and code is below. Disclaimer form stays on screen if I make it the startup form and run the project.

```
Private Sub timerSplash_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerSplash.Tick
    timerSplash.Stop()

    Me.Close()

    Dim disclaimerForm As New Disclaimer()
    disclaimerForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the Shutdown Mode set to? -- You should always specify the .NET version you're targeting

Comment: .Net version is 6.0
Tried on both shutdown modes. Disclaimer form still does not stay up.

Comment: Move  `Me.Close()` after `disclaimerForm.Show()` (with Shutdown Mode set to *after last Form closes*)

Comment: disclaimerForm.Show() closes both the forms. 
disclaimerForm.ShowDialog() keeps the Splash Form open behind the disclaimer form

Comment: Showing a Form doesn't close anything. Note that I wrote `disclaimerForm.Show()`, you don't need `ShowDialog()`, there's already a message loop running, Your app closes when you close the starting Form if that's what it is set to do. You can change that, assuming of course that Application Framework is enabled. But you wouldn't even see the option if it wasn't

Comment: In Shutdown mode, I have two options 
-Shutdown when main form closes 
-Shutdown only after the last form closes.
I choose the second option. After this setting, disclaimerform.Show() will still close everything. 
Showdialog will keep both forms open. 
Is there any other setting I am missing?

Comment: Read again my second comment, apply as described

Comment: Any particular reason that you're not using the spalsh screen functionality that's already built into VB? I haven't tested it other than for a .NET Framework project but it's still there in the project properties for .NET 6, so I assume that it still works. Maybe don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I just created a .NET 6 project and tried to use the built-in splash screen functionality and it didn't work. The relevant properties can be set in the project properties but nothing seems to happen. I know that there are some issues with the application framework in .NET Core projects, so this seems to be one of them. I will see if I can replicate what a .NET Framework project does in a .NET 6 project with some manual changes. That would be better than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Another option would be to do what I demonstrate [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628109). I wrote that for C# because it doesn't have the same application framework functionality that VB does. You could implement the same principles but in VB.

Comment: I just tried a .NET Framework 4.8.1 project in VS 2022 and the splash screen functionality didn't work there either. I know I've used it before and it worked but, in this case, the splash screen disappeared the moment it appeared. The `MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime` property was set to zero by default, which is weird because it's supposed to be 2000. Even when I set it to 3000 manually though, the splash screen still disappeared as soon as the startup form loaded, which should not be the case.

Comment: @jmcilhinney did the splash screen disappear as soon as the startup form loaded, or was  it behind the startup form in the z-order?

Comment: @HardCode, I moved the startup form to check but still didn't see the splash screen. It may have appeared behind the startup form initially though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question per se but, rather, is an alternative way to display a splash screen. It's a better way than what's being used here.

I originally implemented this idea some years ago, to provide splash screen functionality for C# applications that behaved somewhat like the splash screen functionality built into VB apps via the Application Framework. Go [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628109) to see the original C# code and read some explanation of the principles involved.

Here is a VB implementation of that code. Add a new form to your project named `SplashScreen` and add the following code:

```vb
Imports System.Threading
Imports Timer = System.Timers.Timer

Public Class SplashScreen

    Private Structure SplashScreenInfo
        Public StartupForm As Form
        Public MinimumDisplayTime As Integer
        Public Handle As ManualResetEvent
    End Structure

    Private timer As New Timer
    Private minimumDisplayTimeExpired As Boolean = False
    Private syncRoot As New Object
    Private closeHandle As ManualResetEvent

    Private Sub New(startupForm As Form, minimumDisplayTime As Integer)
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler startupForm.Load, AddressOf startupForm_Load

        AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timer_Elapsed
        timer.Interval = minimumDisplayTime
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub DisplaySplashScreen(startupForm As Form, minimumDisplayTime As Integer)
        Dim continueHandle As New ManualResetEvent(False)

        Call New Thread(AddressOf DisplaySplashScreen).Start(New SplashScreenInfo With
                                                             {
                                                                 .StartupForm = startupForm,
                                                                 .MinimumDisplayTime = minimumDisplayTime,
                                                                 .Handle = continueHandle
                                                             })

        continueHandle.WaitOne()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub DisplaySplashScreen(info As Object)
        Dim ssi = DirectCast(info, SplashScreenInfo)
        Dim SplashScreen As New SplashScreen(ssi.StartupForm, ssi.MinimumDisplayTime)

        ssi.Handle.Set()

        Application.Run(SplashScreen)
    End Sub

    Private Sub startupForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        SyncLock syncRoot
            If (Not minimumDisplayTimeExpired) Then
                closeHandle = New ManualResetEvent(False)
            End If
        End SyncLock

        If (closeHandle IsNot Nothing) Then
            closeHandle.WaitOne()
        End If

        Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Close))
    End Sub

    Private Sub timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        SyncLock syncRoot
            If closeHandle Is Nothing Then
                minimumDisplayTimeExpired = True
            Else
                closeHandle.Set()
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

End Class
```

That code handles the `Load` event of the startup form and prevents the event handler completing until a wait handle is triggered. Note that this event handler will always be executed after the forms own `Load` event handler, if there is one, thus any work done to initialise the form in that event handler will be done before waiting. The wait handle is triggered when the `Timer` in the splash screen form raises its `Elapsed` event. The time for that to happen is specified when you call `DisplaySplashScree` in the first place.

Add a module named `Program` to your project and add the following code:

```vb
Module Program

    <STAThread>
    Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

        Dim startupForm = New Form1

        SplashScreen.DisplaySplashScreen(startupForm, 3000)

        Application.Run(startupForm)
    End Sub

End Module
```

This assumes that you have a `Form1` form in your project that you want to be the main/startup form. It creates the startup form, then displays the splash screen, then starts the app with the specified startup form. As mentioned above, that startup form will be initialised but won't be displayed until the splash screen closes, which happens after 3000 milliseconds in this case.

You will need to disable the Application Framework in the project properties and set the startup object to `Sub Main` to make that module the entry point for the app.

I forgot to mention one of the main premises of this code. The splash screen is created and displayed on a different thread to the startup form, just as the VB Application Framework does. The point of that is that it actually enables a splash screen to do what they were originally intended for: to give the user something to look at while the application is initialised. If you display the splash screen by calling `ShowDialog` on the UI thread then that will block and prevent you doing any further work in the startup form. That's fine if your startup form doesn't really do anything and the splash screen is just a billboard. If there is actually initialisation taking place in the startup form though, you need the splash screen to be created on a different thread, so the UI thread is free to do that work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the splash screen *after* you open the new dialog, not before it. Otherwise, if this is the only form, the application will close.

Instead of...

```vb
Private Sub timerSplash_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerSplash.Tick
    timerSplash.Stop()

    Me.Close()

    Dim disclaimerForm As New Disclaimer()
    disclaimerForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

...do this...

```vb
Private Sub timerSplash_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerSplash.Tick
    timerSplash.Stop()

    Dim disclaimerForm As New Disclaimer()
    disclaimerForm.ShowDialog()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

If you want to not show the splash form, use [`Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead of [`ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Make sure to also set the shutdown mode to `OnLastWindowClose` as well.

Comment: I made this change, But the splash form still remains open behind the disclaimer form. In shutdown mode, I have two options
-Shutdown when main form closes
-Shutdown only after the last form closes.
Tried both modes

Comment: If you're using `ShowDialog`, the splash screen will wait for `disclaimerForm` to exit before returning control. Try using `Show` instead.

Comment: I tried with Me.Hide and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I think my mistake is that I kept the Splash form as my main form. I think I should keep a blank form as Main and then build the application around it without ever calling it in the code.

Comment: @AthangTikekar, that was definitely a mistake but your proposed solution is no solution at all.